# How to show certain content to <=IE6 and different one to other browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, xhtml, cross-browser

How to show certain content to IE6 + earlier versions and different one to the others? Is it possible with a conditional comment?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I can only edit a content within <body> tag...

Comment: `Is it possible with a conditional comment?` **Yes**.

Comment: this should help: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: @naveen Post that as an answer, it's the best practice to use IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better option described on Paul Irish blog. ([Link here](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/))

The basic idea is to give class to your `html` tag like this.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Suppose there is a label in your page. For example,

```
<label class="foo">Your browser is IE6!</label>
```

And you wanna display that label only in IE6, do this

```
label.foo { display: none;}
.ie6 label.foo { display: block; }
```

This method sure has its [pros and con](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/#comment-48384)s.

Please read all the other comments in the Paul Irish post for an in depth understanding of the scenario.

Indeed, the best part of a blog post often begins where the blog post ends.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I am able edit just content within <body> tag... So sadly this won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional comments to include content only for certain browsers

More info at:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 1):

use css hacks. Refer below links

http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use ie-specific classes like HTML5 boilperplate do:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then you can have corresponding css to show/hide content, e.g.:

```
.ie6-content: {visible: false;}
.ie6 .ie6-content: {visible: true;}
.content {visible: true;}
.ie6 .content {visible:false}
```

Thus sections with `ie6-content` will be visible for IE6 only, and section with `content` will not be visible in IE6.

Comment: I am able edit just content within <body> tag... So sadly this won't work for me.

Comment: @tomexx I think you can do the same for body tag. just put the class at body level.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments (unfortunately) won't float your boat because they didn't exist until IE 5. Also, they weren't available on netscape. Rather, simply, you put an iframe at the end of your content that displays your actual page contents like so.

```
<title>Your websites title</title>
<body style="margin:0px;font-size:0px;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden">
    <h1>heading</h1>
    <p>Body paragraph</p>
    <!--[if gt IE 6]><!-->
    <iframe frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="main.html" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:white"></iframe>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <style language="css" type="text/css">/*<!--*/
        /* put your limited CSS here */
    /*-->*/</style>
</body>
```

Then, put in a downlevel revealed conditional comment so that the iframe doesn't show up on IE 6 or IE 5. Then, so long as the iframe doesn't have any text contents, it will be invisible in even the first version of the first internet browser.

Then, because no sane person would want to put in enough time, energy, and effort to provide compatibility with IE5 for an ordinary website, you can just use down-level revealed conditional comments (supported before iframes were supported thankfully).

Then, you can add in a little super-basic CSS for browsers like the oldest version of Netscape. Super-basic CSS includes things like color and crop, and excludes things like just about everything cool and modern.

My source for this is, of course, the source code for the world's first website. The most complete bits can be found here: [at cern](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html). It is also the reason for putting the title outside of the head, and not including any head at all.

SO, this method will allow you to display a plain alternative to the webpage to all browsers older than IE 6. You may then ask what about Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and other browsers. Well, those browsers automatically update. So really, there is no real need to extend support to previous versions of them.

At any rate, the above layout is sketcky at best, but hey: it workz. And, that is good enough for me.